The Impact of Pretraining on Fine-tuning and Inference
I am working on a binary prediction classification task, primarily focusing on fine-tuning a BERT model to learn the association between CVEs and CWEs. I've structured my task into three phases: first, using a large dataset of CVE and CWE for MLM pretraining; then using the pretrained model weights for fine-tuning; and finally, using the fine-tuned model with task-specific weights for inference. For inference, I randomly select 100 pairs of CVEs for the model to predict, only retaining the model weights and setting the model to `model.eval()`. However, I've encountered an issue where, after transferring the pretrained model to fine-tuning, the evaluation metrics significantly improve (accuracy, precision, recall, f1), and both training and validation loss decrease substantially. Yet, when I use the fine-tuned model weights for inference, the accuracy turns out to be worse than before.
What is the reason for this discrepancy?
Here are the hyperparameters used for pretraining and fine-tuning:
Pretrain Model:
batch_size = 16

num_epochs = 10

learning_rate = 5e-4

eps = 1e-8

beta1 = 0.9

beta2 = 0.99

weight_decay = 0.01

total_steps = num_epochs \len(train_loader)

warmup_steps = total_steps // 10

early_stopping_patience = 2

mask_prob = 0.15

replace_mask_prob = 0.8

random_replace_prob = 0.10

keep_original_prob = 0.10

Train Model:
learning_rate = 2e-5

batch_size = 16

epoch = 5

I have experimented with various combinations of hyperparameters and found that the current settings are optimal for minimizing validation loss and maximizing accuracy.

I believe this is off-topic for stackoverflow. But you should look into overfitting
